# Install numpy for python 2.7 and not 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have been literally struggling to install numpy for python 2.7 and not 3.4 both of which are on my ubuntu. I have tried:

sudo pip2 install numpy

but it says

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

but when I go to the python shell, and type `import numpy`, it throws an `ImportError`

```
python --version prints `Python 2.7.5`
```

I have no idea what the problem is even after looking at various answers to other SO questions. Is numpy installed and I'm not able to use it for some reason or isn't it installed? Please help.

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
`

Comment: try `python -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: I would recommend you start using `virtualenv`, which allows you to easily control (and reproduce) combinations of interpreters and installed packages.

Comment: @cel Error: `/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: @Sibi, I agree with @jonrsharpe here. The problem is that you installed a local python version into `/usr/local/`, but the interpreter in `/usr/local` does not have pip installed, so you cannot use pip to install numpy for it. The clean way here is to start using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 7):

First, do `pip uninstall numpy` and `pip2 uninstall numpy` just to clean up any old files.

Then, since you are on Ubuntu, you should just run

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

This will install numpy for python2. If you later choose you want it for python3, just run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo pip2 install numpy==1.15.0
```

You need to specify numpy version because latest version requires Python version >= 3.5.