# Reading a binary file from a specific byte

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a binary file from a specific byte (143) until another specific byte (150).

I'm running this command:

```
tail -c +143 full_file.dat | head -c 6 | od -t x1
0000000 20 04 08 13 06 37
0000006
```

I have the values I want (`20 04 08 13 06`).

But, trying the same (at least I'm thinking that) using Python, I'm getting this:

```
'\x04\x08\x13\x067+'
```

The command I'm running in Python is:

```
g = open('full_file.DAT', 'rb')
g.seek(143, 1)
g.read(6)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There seems to be an off-by-one error.

Comment: You're just 1 byte off, 143th byte has offset 142

Comment: Sorry, what you guys mean? from my understanding, I'm reading from byte 143, the next 6 positions 1 by 1.

Comment: So have you just tried to use the number 142 instead of 143? That should get you the result you want, or not?

Comment: I tried, that was the output :
>>> g.seek(142,1)
>>> g.read(6)

'\x12\x83\x08B\x00a'

Not what I want.

Comment: I think what I'm missing here is to convert the output to hexadecimal\decimal...

Comment: try `>>>g.seek(142)` `>>>g.read(6)`. `g.seek(142,1)` is starting your `seek` relative to your current position in the file. `g.seek(142)` will start it from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using Numpy :

```
import Numpy as np

arr = np.fromfile('full_file.DAT', dtype='uint8')
arr[143:143+6] #==> [20 04 08 13 06 37]
```

Comment: You probably meant `arr[143:143+6]`.

Comment: I would try that, but, I'm using Python 2.7.5, do you have other suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810671/install-numpy-for-python-2-7-and-not-3-4

Comment: I installed numpy, but the output was different( 4,  8, 19,  6, 55, 43), that dtype='uint8' is converting everything to int? If yes, that is the case now,  I need to convert the binary info to hexa, I tried to convert the output of your suggestion into a hex, but, didn't work.

Comment: The value returned by my example are decimal, I didn't understand that you want hexadecimal values. Anyway the important thing is that the values match whatever is the base used to represent them. If `[20 04 08 13 06 37]` is a list of hex, `arr[143:143+6]` should return `[32 04 08 19 06 55]`. So apparently your index should be 142 instead of 143. Can you try this : `arr[142:142+6] ?

Comment: No, didn't work also, just recap, I'm working with a binary file, I can get the data as I want using a bash command(the first command in the 1st post), but, the point I need to do the same in python.

Comment: Difficult to help you without the file... What's the returned sequence when using arr[142:142+6] ? It should be `32 4 8 19 6 55` (with a doubt for 32 however) because you told me that arr[143:143+6]  returned `4, 8, 19, 6, 55, 43`. Decreasing the index should rotate the sequence to the right, so a new number should appear at first place (I guess 32) and 43 should disappear from the end of the sequence. Please double check what you're doing because with only one index of difference between 143 and 142, **5 of the 6 numbers must remain the same**.

Comment: Hey Dspr, thanks for all your help, but, I managed to get the info I wanted, basically I used the same shell command. 
>>> import os
>>> os.popen("tail -c +143 full_file.dat | head -c 6 | od -An -t x1").read().strip().split("  ")
['20 04 08 13 06 37']